# If "A" text is in "A" cell, return "X" text, If "B" text is in "A" Cell return "Y" Text, If "C" Text is in "A" cell, return "Z" Text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking to automate as much of my spreadsheet as possible. In one column I have over 30 variables that are always abbreviated with other additional information and in the next column I want it to say the full word for the abbreviation. For Example:

```
Column 1      Column 2
xxx-a-xxx     Apple
xxx-b-xxx     Banana
xxx-c-xxx     Cranberry
xxx-d-xxx     Dragon Fruit
xxx-e-xxx     Egg Plant
```

I want an equation that can check for all my variables and return the correct word in column 2, and as mentioned I have over 30 variables, I want to make sure it checks for -a-,-b-,-c-,-d-,-e-... and whichever one it finds it will it will return the designated word for that abbreviation.

I first tried:

```
=IF([@Asset]="*-a-*","apple","")
```

But this did not work at all.
Then googled around and tried:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-a-",A1)),"apple")
```

But could not find a way to add additional variables.

Is what I'm looking to do even possible?

Thanks in advance.

To answer some questions, creating a new column would defeat the purpose as the information is input into the table  as "Building code-unit abbreviation-unit number"

So as another example table will look like

```
Column 1           Column 2

ABC-EF-001         Exhaust Fan
ABC-EF-002         Exhaust Fan
ABC-FU-001         Furnace
ABC-FU-002         Furnace
ABC-GEN-001        Generator
```

Thank you to everyone for your solutions. Very much appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you create a column that has ONLY the abbreviations?  Then you can use VLOOKUP.

Comment: .... aka a lookup table.

Comment: Is the data in column with abbreviations always formatted the same?  Every variable in the same position within the string and each variable separated with a "-"?  If it's reliably consistent, then you can use Index(TextSplit(ABBREVIATIONS,"-"),[position in ABBREVIATIONS of the data you want to extract]) to extract the needed value. Then it's just a matter of an XLOOKUP against a lookup table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited Post After OP's Updated Query:**

As already mentioned above in comments and posted in answer also, using a <kbd>LOOKUP TABLE</kbd> definitely makes it easier. Here is what I came up with, using <kbd>XLOOKUP( )</kbd> with <kbd>TEXTSPLIT( )</kbd> and another alternative version with <kbd>LOOKUP( )</kbd> function for those not using `MS365`, I hope it works as well.

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=XLOOKUP("-"&CHOOSECOLS(TEXTSPLIT(A2,"-"),2)&"-",$E$2:$E$9,$F$2:$F$9)
```

---

Or,

[image]

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/SEARCH($E$2:$E$9,A2),$F$2:$F$9)
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd> --> For case-sensitive.

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/FIND($E$2:$E$9,A2),$F$2:$F$9)
```

---

Another way using <kbd>XLOOKUP( )</kbd> with <kbd>TEXTBEFORE( )</kbd> &  <kbd>TEXTAFTER( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=XLOOKUP("-"&TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A2:A11,"-"),"-")&"-",E2:E9,F2:F9)
```

---

Comment: ```=LOOKUP(2,1/SEARCH(Table93[Abbreviation],[@Asset]),Table93[Full Name])``` I found success using this with a Lookup Table in another sheet.

Answer (score 6):

Create a lookup table:

[image]

Then use FILTER:

```
=FILTER($F$2:$F$6,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$2:$E$6,A2)))
```

[image]

---

Or if one does not have FILTER:

```
=INDEX($F$2:$F$6,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$2:$E$6,A2)),),0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's better to list them and use a lookup variation as in Scott's reply, but this could be used:

`=CHOOSE(TOCOL(1/ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"-a-","-b-","-c-","-d-","-e-"},A2))*{1,2,3,4,5},3),"Apple","Banana","Cranberry","Dragon Fruit","Egg Plant")`

It searches the cell for the array of search strings and multiplies the result with the position of the CHOOSE function to return.

Older version of Excel:
`=INDEX({"Apple","Banana","Cranberry","Dragon Fruit","Egg Plant"},AGGREGATE(15,6,{1,2,3,4,5}/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"-a-","-b-","-c-","-d-","-e-"},A2))),1))`

Comment: make it dynamic : `=INDEX($F$2:$F$6,TOCOL(1/ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$2:$E$6,A2))*(ROW($E$2:$E$6)-1),3))` I think good use of `TOCOL()` here.

Comment: I attempted to use this but I did not find success. Like this, ```=CHOOSE(TOCOL(1/ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"-a-","-b-","-c-","-d-","-e-"},A41))*{1,2,3,4,5},3),"Apple","Banana","Cranberry","Dragon Fruit","Egg Plant")``` and like this ```=CHOOSE(TOCOL(1/ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"-a-","-b-","-c-","-d-","-e-"},[@ASSET]))*{1,2,3,4,5},3),"Apple","Banana","Cranberry","Dragon Fruit","Egg Plant")``` I was not sure how to go about with the index suggestion

Comment: @BCOR can you show that in a screenshot what error you are getting in or why you don't find success? Because it is working on my end as per the given data in the OP. Infact all the solutions posted here are working, as per the given data, now if you have something else, we cant say.

Comment: Does your Excel version support `TOCOL`? (What version do you use).

Comment: I use excel 2016 currently. I believe that may have been the issue because the updated formula for the older version of excel did work. Thanks! For my reference what does the 1 at the end of the formula as well as the 15,6 earlier reference ? ```=INDEX({"Apple","Banana","Cranberry","Dragon Fruit","Egg Plant"},AGGREGATE(15,6,{1,2,3,4,5}/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"-a-","-b-","-c-","-d-","-e-"},A2))),1))```

Comment: @BCOR it is very simple, it is hard-coded that is why it is working with 5 variables, where as you have 31, you need to create a lookup table as already mentioned here.

Comment: @BCOR also for your reference, in `AGGREGATE()` function, `15` refers to `SMALL()` function, while `6` refers to `ignore error values`, while `1` denotes to the `kth` value.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya thanks for filling in. Forgot to explain further.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

=XLOOKUP(INDEX(TEXTSPLIT([@[Column 1]],"-"),2),Table5[Code],Table5[Fruit],"")

If the data in Column 1 uses a consistent format (each code is in the same position and you're using a "-" as a separator), you can use this same formula for any code by simply changing the value in the INDEX formula (currently "2") and pointing your XLOOKUP to the appropriate table and columns.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following for a slightly different application:

=IF(FIND("a",A19,1)>0,1,0)

So find() returns a number showing the position the character is found, you might need to wrap find() in iferror() though.

After that you can go to a lookup table or similar.